# Is the EMP threat to the power grid supported by physics?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, estimation, electronics, shock-waves

Every once in a while I come across some article saying that our modern power grid could be knocked out of commission for up to a year by an electromagnetic pulse.  I'm skeptical of such warnings.

Is there any good scientific research that addresses this purported threat?

---

How is this off-topic?  What other science would address this question?  It's a legitimate, and important question.  It is, in fact the ethical duty of the physics community to have answers to these kinds of questions.

Comment: How big of an EMP are you contemplating for this question?

Comment: Might [skeptics.se] be better suited for this claim verification?

Comment: The only kind of EMP that actually poses a serious risk would be that originating from a large atmospheric nuclear bomb detonation.  However, how much effect a nuclear blast would have on the power grid is a contentious subject of debate, and the most reliable evaluations of the risk may be classified.

Answer (score 2):

It’s more of an engineering question than a pure science one, so a place to look for research is the IEEE. There’s a lot there. For example, the first hit on my search was [“Unaddressed threat to power grid infrastructure: Electromagnetic pulse” (IEEE 2016)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8079355) with abstract:

> Detonation of a nuclear weapon at high altitude, produces high
>   magnitude Electromagnetic Pulse (EMP which will cover the extensive
>   geographic region within the line of sight of detonation. This high
>   magnitude EMP when interact with sensitive electronics network, has
>   the competence to produce extensive and long eternal disruption and
>   destruction to the critical power infrastructures like power grids
>   that is sufficient to underpin the fabric of an economy. A single EMP
>   attack seriously degrade or shut down a large part of the electric
>   power grid in the geographic area of EMP exposure effectively
>   instantaneously. In this paper, impact of EMP on power grid has been
>   critically highlighted and an effort of understanding about the
>   interaction of EMP with electrical power infrastructure has been made.
>   Moreover, EMP as a threat to national security has been underlined and
>   techniques of mitigations are also recommended.

See also “[Electromagnetic Warfare Is Here” (IEEE Spectrum 2014)](https://www.google.com/amp/s/spectrum.ieee.org/aerospace/military/electromagnetic-warfare-is-here.amp.html) and the rather chilling work in “[Electromagnetic Warfare and the Cybersecurity Threat” (IEEE 2017)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8328461)

A quick survey search didn’t find any published research arguing that there is no such effect.

From the science and policy side, the National Academies have published “[Terrorism and the Electric Power Delivery System](https://www.nap.edu/read/12050/chapter/9)”, which addresses the issues of recovery from a number of scenarios, including what extends recovery time. 
Briefly, a localized outage recovers much quickly if it can get power, people and parts from adjacent areas. It’s much harder to recover organically, without that support because the adjacent areas are out. Additionally, there are only a limited number of spares for certain critical, but long lasting, pieces of infrastructure. It would take a very long time to manufacture large numbers of those, especially without power.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was a quite [significant solar activity event in 1859,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_storm_of_1859) when the electrification of our cities was still in its infancy.

The event heavily ionized the upper atmosphere, and induced strong currents in the ground, to the degree that telegraph operators could communicate over landline with their batteries disconnected (the power being supplied by the ground).
Such an event would wreak utter havoc today, on a global scale.

Comment: That's not a complete answer, but the report seems plausible based on my experience.  When I was an electronics tech in the Army, we had a radar with a tuning drive motor that kept running until the data cable was removed.  I found out that it even ran when the power cable to the radar was removed.  So "obviously" the power was coming from the control van.  But the motor kept turning, even when all power cables were dropped.  The voltage was due to a potential difference between the ground straps on the radar and on the van.  In the case or the telegraph, that might have been weather related.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton: Well, less weather, more space-weather related. The currents in the ground result from large-scale (~100s of kms) horizontal gradients in the eletrostatic field that exists between the ground and the upper atmosphere. Those fields are strengthened from the overabundance of charges during a Carrington-type event, or after a nuclear EMP. And in the same way as during an EMP, those electrostatic fields can be strong enough to short-circuit all the little MOSFETS that our technology is currently based on.

Comment: In this way, the currents in the ground are just an effect of the electrostatic fields that can kill transistors. Hence, the nuclear EMP and the Carrington-type natural event both work in similar ways, just on different timescales.